# Not the whole site using SSL

Tags: .htaccess, http, magento, ssl, https

Our site, www.divestyle.co.uk uses an SSL certificate throughout the site, except when it goes to the online shop which is built in Magento, all on the same hosting. I built the main site which uses the SSL and the wordpress blog but for some reason the shop does not.

http://www.divestyle.co.uk/dive-shop/scuba-diving/regulators.html

You can see that the URL does not have the SSL padlock on.

Any ideas why not? We had some issues with the htaccess with the redirects which we fixed on another question, so I am adding the htaccess file on here too in case we need to add something to it. We obviously want to make sure that changing the URL to https will not affect any of the sales we can receive.

```
# -- concrete5 urls start --

# -- Force www: #
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

# force https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.divestyle.co.uk/$1 [R,L]

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
# -- Wordpress #
RewriteRule ^divestyle_blog/index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule divestyle_blog/. divestyle_blog/index.php [L]
# -- /Wordpress #
# --Magento #
RewriteRule ^dive-shop/index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule dive-shop/. dive-shop/index.php [L]
# -- /Magento #
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}/index.html !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}/index.php !-f
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# -- concrete5 urls end --
```

**------- UPDATE -------**

I have changed my .htaccess file so the 2nd one matches this, RewriteRule ^(.*)$ but the site is still coming as insecure. See the screenshots. It mentions about the images.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/3w6sfnjn8pgcxg8/Screenshot%202017-12-13%2007.38.04.png?dl=0

https://www.dropbox.com/s/zw8ujcg2wj9arpp/Screenshot%202017-12-13%2007.37.58.png?dl=0

When I asked the developer about the issues, he sent me this, not sure if this helps get to the bottom of this:

> The 'httponly' option has been created like this on purpose. There is a type of website attack called XSS.
>   If someone managed to inject some javascript code onto your site (which on some sites can be via adverts) then they would be able to read the contents of any cookies. If the cookie contained a session id for a logged in user they would be able to read that and send it back out to someone and they would be able to log in as that user without requiring their username and password. A 'httponly' option tells the browser that the cookie should only be sent over http (which includes https in this definition) and not made available to javascript or anything else running within the local browser.”

Comment: Have you set "used Secured URL in frontend" to Yes from admin?

Comment: @DhirenVasoya yes this is set in the admin.

Comment: @ChrisD, your shop responds to https requests, that's ok.
The problem is with links. Some are https-based (such as login page) others are hardcoded as http - links to products. I'd suggest there are problems with template. May be http scheme is hardcoded there.

Comment: @PakUula I have updated the ticket with a screenshot of what error comes up under the http. Hope this may help resolve it a little.

Comment: @ChrisD, the browser tells you that some of the content is loaded over insecure connection. I opened your site and found that some images are loaded through HTTP. For instance `<img src="http://www.divestyle.co.uk/dive-shop/media/wysiwyg/infortis/ultimo/menu/custom/ContactUs_ThumbsUp_M.png" class="fade-on-hover" alt="Contact Us" />`.
I'd bet you should fix the template. Such links look like hardcoded.

Comment: @PakUula How can I find out how to get all the content loaded over a secure connection instead of some of it. It mentions about the images. Would this maybe be external images not hosted on this URL that are not using https? I need to go through all the hard coded links and remove the http:// as this is not needed.

Comment: @ChrisD, Quick and dirty hack is to replace all complete URLs with partial. E.g. instead of `http://example.com/path` you put just `/path`

Comment: @PakUula I will give that a go, thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is probably guilty because of a bad syntax :
    RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://www.divestyle.co.uk/$1 [R,L]

You should match ^/(.*)$ as on the first rule

Comment: @ EugèneAdell - I have updated my ticket, it would be great if you could take a look

Comment: As said by others, you have a mix content because some images aren't downloaded in SSL. You have absolute links such as : <img src="http://www.divestyle.co.uk/dive-shop/media/wysiwyg/infortis/ultimo/menu/custom/ContactUs_ThumbsUp_M.png" class="fade-on-hover" alt="Contact Us" style="opacity: 1;"> instead of relative ( src="/dive-shop/ ... )

Answer (score 0):

Forcing https is like magic. I had to try multiple solutions from the internet, that people claimed to work, and they didn't on my server.

Here is my snippet, that works ;)

```
# SSL
RewriteCond %{ENV:HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

Try it instead of your rule under `# force https` comment.